# Mysql: Insert Procedure with two tables (FK)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im trying to make an stored Procedure that makes an insert into tables. 
The insert effects two tables and there is an FK between them.

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `db`.`add_user_hr` (
    IN in_Pass VARCHAR(45),
    IN in_Value VARCHAR(45),
    IN in_HR_ID INT,
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HR
        (
            Value
        )
        VALUES
        (
            in_Value
        );

    INSERT INTO User
        (
            Password,
            HR_idHR
        )
        VALUES
        (
            in_Pass,
            (Get the ID from HR)
        );
END
```

How do I make sure that the correct id gets into User. And
if there is a error in the insert into HR, who do I make
sure it dosent tyr to make an insert into User? Ive
looked into "commit" but don't know how it's used.
Or is there a better way to do this?

In this example I have table UserType. Is this needed to 
to find out witch type of user it is later on? And
how do I user this in the insert, select procedure in the
future?

Thx for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If PK (primary key) has AUTO_INCREMENT options than you can do something like this:

```
declare value_id_v INT;
insert into hr(value) values(value_in);

set value_id_v = last_insert_id();
```

Now you can use `value_id_v` to do inserts. Here is the link to read about this function [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: If there is many using this procedure at the same time is there a chanse that the last_insert_id(); is acually wrong?